# jquery mobile how to refresh internal page after navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-refresh

Hi I develop a mobile app in html5 and JS.

I have the below html with all pages that I use

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    //<some dynamic listview>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
</div>
```

In my app I go from page2 to page3 and after some functions I have to go back to page2 but I'm trying to refresh it with no success.

I use the below code in order to go back from page3 to page2

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page2', 'slideup', true, true);
```

How can I refresh page2 after change page?

I try the below code

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page2', 'slideup', {reloadPage: true});
```

with no success.

I am stuck.

Thx in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function refreshPage(page){
    // Page refresh
    page.trigger('pagecreate');
    page.listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: sorry for my question but how to use refreshPage function. Where to add it?